# Angular 1.6: Data not showing until scope function execute

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

Title might sound a bit strange but that's how it is.

Code:

```
angular.module('app')


.controller('TenantsCtrl', ['$scope', 'tenantsService','$window','loginService', function ($scope, tenantsService, $window, loginService) {
    $scope.mode = "list";
    $scope.g = [];
    $scope.editTenant = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      room: "",
      to: "",
      from: ""
    }
    tenantsService.get().then((data) => {
        data.tenants.map((tenant) => {
          tenant.to = new Date(tenant.to).toLocaleDateString('ro-RO')
          tenant.from = new Date(tenant.from).toLocaleDateString('ro-RO')
        });
        console.log(typeof data.tenants);
        $scope.g = data.tenants;
        console.log($scope.g)
      }).catch((reason) => {
        loginService.doLogout();
        if(confirm(`${reason}. Please login`)) {
          $window.location.href="#!/login";
        }
      })
  $scope.showTenantForm = function(tenant) {
    console.log($scope.g)
  }


 }]);
```

View:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Cazati <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="showTenantForm()">Cazeaza</button></h1>
</div>
<div class="row"  ng-cloak>
    {{g}}
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Camera</th>
                <th>Cazat din</th>
                <th>Cazat pana la</th>
                <th>Cazat de</th>
                <!--<th>Status</th>-->
                <th>Modifica</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in g">
                <td>{{x.lastName}} {{x.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{x.room}}</td>
                <td>{{x.to}}</td>
                <td>{{x.from}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="editTenant(tenant.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Modifica</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Problem: data from table isn't shown. Strangely it gets shown only when press the button from header and the function gets called.

Data from service comes correctly.

Update: tenantsService

```
angular.module('app')
.service('graphQLService', ['baseUrl', 'loginService', function (baseUrl, loginService) {
  var graphQLService = {};
  graphQLService.sendQuery = function (query, vars) {
    var self = this;
    vars = vars || {};
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // use fetch to get the result
      fetch(baseUrl + '/gql', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query,
          vars,
          authToken: loginService.getToken()
        })
      })

      .then(function(response) {
        var status = response.status;
        if(status != 401) {
          return response.json().then((res) => {
            resolve(res.data);
          })
        } else {
          reject(response.statusText);
        }
        if(response.status == 401) {

        }
      })
      .catch(reject);
    });
  };
  return graphQLService;
}]);
```

Comment: Did you try to add a `Scope.$apply()` after `$scope.g = data.tenants;`?

Comment: Ok. Adding this solves the problem. Can you explain why is needed? maybe add it as an aswer to accept it :)

Comment: Sure, doing it right now

Comment: are you using the standard $http service for the request inside `tenantsService.get()`?

Comment: nope. i've updated the question with something i called graphql service. 

In tenantsService.get i do
return graphQLService.sendQuery('query {tenants { id firstName lastName room from to users { username }}}');

Comment: yeah that's why you needed to explicitly call the `$apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `$scope.$apply()` after you get your response and you manipulate your data, and after that you assign your data to your `g` scope variable. So:

```
$scope.g = data.tenants;
$scope.$apply();
```

AngularJS already wraps a lot of its code inside the `$scope.$apply` method. This in order to trigger the `$scope.$digest` method, which is the one responsible for refreshing all the bindings inside the related scope and update the values and so the views. 
For example, if you were using the custom `$http` service, it's executed inside the `$scope.$apply`, so you don't need to call it explicitly. 
In your case, you are not using the standard `$http`, so you need to trigger it manually.

The code was working after calling the other function because the `ng-click` is wrapped inside the `$apply` as well, so it refreshes all the bindings in the scope.

If you want to read more about it, this is a pretty good article:

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much :) I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `data.tenants.map` returns you a new array. You don't save the reference to it.

Have you tried to do this

```
$scope.g = data.tenants.map((tenant) => {
      tenant.to = new Date(tenant.to).toLocaleDateString('ro-RO');
      tenant.from = new Date(tenant.from).toLocaleDateString('ro-RO');
      return tenant;
    });
    console.log(typeof data.tenants);
    console.log($scope.g)
```

Comment: .map replaces elements in the current array. Also tried with a foreach and a separate var. No result.

$scope.tentantsList gets it's values but it doesn't get shown on page :(

Comment: is it custom implementation of `map` method of the array?
Please see the reference to `map` method of the Array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example

Comment: nope. worth mentioning: removing the ".map" step leads to same result. I don't think that this produces the problem

Comment: Map element should return edited element which will be pushed to new array. I've forgot to add it.